# how to get contact email if available

Tags: android, json, email, contacts

Hi i am new to android development so pardon me if its silly
i want to get the email and other details of contacts in my phone and store them in JSON
here is my code

can any one help me with other parameters of contacts like email address and other stuff it would be very helpfull.

```
private void getNumber(ContentResolver cr2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Cursor cur = cr2.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
            null, null);
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        try {
            obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("name",
                    cur.getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)));
            obj.put("number",
                    cur.getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
            arobj.put(a, obj);
            a++;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        contactsObj.put("contacts", arobj);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        Toast.makeText(ContactsToPdf.this, "done", 500).show();
        cur.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the good path just keep on adding lines

You can look to the different fields in :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.html

```
 Cursor cur = cr2.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
            null, null);
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        try {
            obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("email",cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS)));
            arobj.put(a, obj);
            a++;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i want to get the email associated with the contact like i have a number that has a email id also how to get that